# If Milei is able to apply his economic plan during the next decade, what are the chances of Argentina becoming (once again) a major economy?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, economic-growth, political-economy, argentina

Once Argentina was one of the strongest economies in South America. It is pretty clear that the economic model that made Argentina successful then does not stand a big chance to work again. Javier Milei proposes major changes in Argentina's way of dealing with the economy of the country. I speak not just about the dollarization to combat rampant inflation but also about his plans to increase freedom in trade and in business. So I want to ask the experts about the chances that these measures have to work and if, with them, Argentina's economy could eventually surpass the economies of other countries with a similar population, like South Korea or even Germany.

Comment: What exactly is his plan? Cursory google search does not show any English report detailing, in economic terms, his plan. Moreover, if the number of measures he proposes is large it might be too broad for one SE question. Also how do you define major economy? Also, surpassing South Korea or Germany might happen even if their economy collapses without any improvement to argentina so it would be best if you would specify it in some GDP/capita terms or something like that. Also, what timeframe we are talking about?

Comment: @1muflon1 Suppose OP answers all your questions. Is a non opinion-based answer possible then?

Comment: @Giskard sure one can predict direction of effect of policy x on economic growth. You can use estimates from other countries to give some numbers to that and then come with estimate. For example, if policy is increasing trade openness one can pull from literature mean estimates of effect on this on growth and then it’s just matter of simple arithmetic to calculate n of years required to reach GDp/c of y

Comment: Looking forward to this answer once you get an English translation of Milei's economic program